# How to rank a cell value within the same cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, ranking-functions

I am trying to rank a set of numbers (in a column), but I want that rank to appear next to the number in the same cell.

For example, if the number is "21" and that ranks "3rd" – I would want the cell to read "21 (3)". **BONUS POINTS if I can format the (3) to be smaller/superscript.**

---

**WHAT I'VE TRIED:**
While the cell I am working in already has an equation in it, I will simplify it. Let's say **A23 = 15** and **A24 = 6**. I have tried the following equation but it keeps giving me an error. The cell I am working in is H103. The range for ranking is H103:H114.

```
=SUM(A23+A24) & "(" & RANK(H103,$H$103:$H$114) & ")"
```

Even if I remove the parentheses or rework that a bit, I am still left with an error. Just trying to find any way I can have 2 formulas, with different results in the same cell; one of which showing the rank of that particular cell.

**[HERE IS COPY OF MY SHEET](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LvbNTO7ENuo1vbsCE5c0b0N7kJN32wlSh6jhXtFvsWE/edit?usp=sharing)** — This is a duplicated Google Sheet, so feel free to play around in there if you'd like. I am focusing on ranking H103:H114.

Comment: @player0 added copy of sheet link into post – thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

paste in cell **H103**:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(VLOOKUP(B103:B114, QUERY(INDIRECT($A$100&"!B:C"), 
 "select B,sum(C) where B is not null group by B", 0), 2, 0)+
 VLOOKUP(B103:B114, QUERY(INDIRECT($A$100&"!E:D"), 
 "select E,sum(D) where E is not null group by E", 0), 2, 0), "#.00")&" "&CHAR(8317)&
 VLOOKUP(RANK(VLOOKUP(B103:B114, QUERY(INDIRECT($A$100&"!B:C"), 
 "select B,sum(C) where B is not null group by B", 0), 2, 0)+
 VLOOKUP(B103:B114, QUERY(INDIRECT($A$100&"!E:D"), 
 "select E,sum(D) where E is not null group by E", 0), 2, 0), 
 VLOOKUP(B103:B114, QUERY(INDIRECT($A$100&"!B:C"), 
 "select B,sum(C) where B is not null group by B", 0), 2, 0)+
 VLOOKUP(B103:B114, QUERY(INDIRECT($A$100&"!E:D"), 
 "select E,sum(D) where E is not null group by E", 0), 2, 0), 0),  
 {1,  CHAR(185);             2, CHAR(178);            3, CHAR(179);  
  4,  CHAR(8308);            5, CHAR(8309);           6, CHAR(8310);           
  7,  CHAR(8311);            8, CHAR(8312);           9, CHAR(8313); 
  10, CHAR(185)&CHAR(8304); 11, CHAR(185)&CHAR(185); 12, CHAR(185)&CHAR(178)}, 2, 0)&
 CHAR(8318))
```

[image]

---

paste in cell **I103**:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(B103:B114, QUERY(INDIRECT($A$100&"!B:C"), 
 "select B,sum(C) where B is not null group by B", 0), 2, 0)+
 VLOOKUP(B103:B114, QUERY(INDIRECT($A$100&"!E:D"), 
 "select E,sum(D) where E is not null group by E", 0), 2, 0)-C103:C114)
```

---

paste in cell **L103**:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(B103:B114, QUERY(INDIRECT($A$100&"!B:C"), 
 "select B,sum(C) where B is not null group by B", 0), 2, 0)+
 VLOOKUP(B103:B114, QUERY(INDIRECT($A$100&"!E:D"), 
 "select E,sum(D) where E is not null group by E", 0), 2, 0)-J103:J114)
```

---

conditional formatting for **H** column:

**red** color custom formula:

```
=REGEXMATCH(H103, CHAR(8317)&CHAR(185)&CHAR(178)&CHAR(8318))
```

**green** color custom formula:

```
=REGEXMATCH(H103, CHAR(8317)&CHAR(185)&CHAR(8318))
```

Comment: Thank you! @player0 I had to reverse the order of the rankings so that the higher numbers we're ranked #1 as opposed to #12 – but that was an easy fix of just descending order in the code you provided

Now just working through how that affects my other cells – appreciate it